# Are css errors recorded anywhere?

Tags: css

I understand that if a sytle is overridden then it is crossed out in Google Chrome tools and then you can go to the Computed tab to see, which element has overridden the style.

Say I have some css like this:

```
.myClass
{
    position:static;
    top: 20px;
}
```

This is clearly wrong because the top attribute does not work with positions that are static.  When I load the webpage in Google Chrome and press F12; the style appears under the styles tab as if it was applied to the webpage, which I find a little confusing.

Does Google Chrome (or any other browser/tool) tell you what the error is e.g. "cannot apply top to statically applied element" (like you get in Visual Studio when there is an error in your code e.g. NullPointerException).

Comment: "This is clearly wrong because the top attribute does not work with positions that are static." -  **not necessarily**. Remember that CSS properties are inherited and also "cascade" down: a child element could have `top: inherit;` so it inherits it from `.myClass` if it's parent is `.myClass` - so that could be one reason to set `top: ` on an element for which it has no immediate effect.

Comment: @Dai, thanks.  So if myClass has a position of static, then it could have a top attribute as long as it is inherited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla Firefox has such a feature. It tells you why a rule isn't applied directly in the Inspector.

Comment: I see what you mean - thanks for that +1.  Do you use it? Is it accurate when you have complex cascades?

Comment: Yeah, I like to use it especially when I don't know why something isn't applied. Seems to work fine with complex cascades, so for me it's a definite thumbs up

Answer (score 3):

A CSS class is a set of rules applicable to any element on your page that also can change during the live time of the page. As mentioned in Dais comment, properties are inherited and cascade down.

There is no reliable way to validate a set of CSS rules, because they all interplay each other and are about to change. Especially if you ask for a feature in your IDE like the NullPointerException hint this won't work, because CSS classes are composable and are JIT compiled. An IDE could not know beforehand which class are combined with other classes assigned to which elements in regards to the DOM tree at a specific app time state.

Comment: Thanks for: " they all interplay each other and are about to change".  I guess one scenario is where JavaScript changes the position from static to absolute making the top attribute valid?

Comment: Before I mark the answer, could you have a look at Dais comment? I believe his scenario involves removing the position attribute from myClass and therefore if a non static position is inherited then the top attribute will have an effect of myClass.  Is that how you understood it?

Comment: Yes, my answer is just a more general answer to the problem. Elements always have a certain set of CSS properties, even if you don't assign anything to them. Most of the time those values are `inherit` or `initial`. If you remove a set property, the prop isn't gone, but reset to either the closest cascade or the `initial` or `inherit` value.

Comment: Firefox does have the feature I was looking for as per mikes answer.  +1 for " they all interplay each other and are about to change".